# SOAP request and response in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm absolutely new in this question. I need to get Token from SOAP request in PHP.

Request

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"> 
       <soap:Header/> 
       <soap:Body> 
          <tem:GetToken> 
             <tem:WebChanelID>8</tem:WebChanelID> 
             <tem:AccessCode>444555</tem:AccessCode> 
          </tem:GetToken> 
       </soap:Body> 
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Server https://hma.ecvi.ru/service/webform.wsdl.php

Comment: This is an xml format so you'll need to use an XML parser for that, or regex if you just want the one property, check this https://regex101.com/r/Brz2WF/1

Comment: i found some solution for me (bellow), but it's not working. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What i do wrong here?

```
$soapUrl = "https://hma.ecvi.ru/service/webform.wsdl.php";

$xml_post_string = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"> 
   <soap:Header/> 
   <soap:Body> 
      <tem:GetToken> 
         <tem:WebChanelID>631</tem:WebChanelID> 
         <tem:AccessCode>989</tem:AccessCode> 
      </tem:GetToken> 
   </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"POST /package/package_1.3/packageservices.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: hma.ecvi.ru",
"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
);

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
    $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
echo $parser;
```

Comment: You need to update your question. Nobody will check your answer.